# Java create new instance of class based on another class

Tags: java, class, object

Say I have 2 arrays of objects which all extend the same abstract class, and I want the second list's first element to be a new instance of the same class which the first element in the first array is (this assumes that they take the same parameters).

```
Animals[] animals1 = new Animals[] {new Cat(), new Dog()...}

Animals[] animals2 = new Animals[] {new animals1[0].getClass()} //doesn't work obviously
```

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: You could either use reflection or the (abstract) factory pattern.

Comment: Quick summary on reflection http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/constructors.html

Comment: Perhaps having Animal and it's subclasses implement Cloneable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

Animal.java

```
public interface Animal {
}
```

Cat.java:

```
public class Cat implements Animal {
}
```

Dog.java:

```
public class Dog implements Animal {
}
```

Code to do the mapping:

```
Animal[] animals1 = new Animal[] {new Cat(), new Dog()};
Animal[] animals2 = Arrays.stream(animals1).map(a -> {
    Animal animal = null;
    try {
        animal = a.getClass().getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return animal;
}).toArray(Animal[]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create an abstract method `newInstance()` in the abstract base class, and make the subclasses create and return its own kind.  For instance,

```
public abstract class Animal {
   // ... other methods
   public abstract Animal newInstance(/* parameters */);
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
    // ... other methods, fields
    @Override
    public Animal newInstance(/* parameters */) {
        Dog d = new Dog(/* ... */);
        // ...
        return d;
    }
}
// do this for other animals, they should instantiate and return their class
```

and for the list:

```
Animals[] animals2 = new Animals[] {animals[0].newInstance(/* ... */), ...};
```